# Sensor Fusion of Accelerometer and Gyroscope in Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope, sensor-fusion

I am trying to use the phone as a gun aiming with the gyroscope. I calibrate with the phone or tablet in a certain orientation. This will shoot straight. Then depending on the direction the phone is turned (left/right/up/down.), the gun shoots in that direction.

I am using the gyroscope. And all this works. Except after shooting for about 30 secs, the gyroscope slowly starts drifting towards left or right. So when I go back to the orientation I calibrated with, it doesn't shoot straight anymore. Does anyone have any experience writing a Complementary or Kalman Filter to fuse gyro and accelerometer data to give better results in Unity 3D?

I've found this online - http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-ahrs-with-x-imu/. It seems to do exactly what I want. But I am using it wrong. I sometime get better and sometimes get worse results with. Anybody have any experience with it ?

Answer (score 0):

First place, Gyro/accelerometer fusion will stabilize your pitch/roll angles, since gravity indicates in which direction ground is. However, you cannot correct "left/right" drift because actual heading is unknown. Getting proper heading stabilization cannot be achieved with gyro/accelerometer alone: it requires additional information.

The example you provide (Madgwick’s MARG/IMU filter) is a filter that can integrate magnetometers ("north" reference), but it has two requirements for getting good results:

- The magnetometer has been properly calibrated.
- There are no magnetic field disturbances. This is generally not true if you are indoors, or if you are moving close to power lines or metallic structures.

An alternative is using a video signal to get optical flow information, or detecting if the phone is resting in a fixed position to compensate gyro biases from time to time.